# Cipher blocksize return 0 in Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have to do an integration of our Java Enterprise application with one of our clients. We call the IdP and get back the XML. Part of the return, is <e:CipherData><e:CipherValue> and the  details are in xenc:CipherDataxenc:CipherValue. If I use the https://www.samltool.com/decrypt.php and pass the returned data and insert our private key, then EVERYTHING is cleaned and can read the decrypted XML data.
Doesn’t matter, what I do in Java I can’t decrypt the returned information. The first piece is 344 bytes and the second is over 4k.

When I’m reading the private key it is telling me the algorithm is RSA and the format is PKCS#8. The created cipher tells me that the blocksize is 0.
What can I do to process the decryption? Spent days googling all pieces but now I’m fully stacked. Looking for ANY help and I even can contract this problem out.

```
public static String testPrivateKeyPEM = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
            + "MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDBzQjFSrnpm8Li"
. . .
. . .
            + "wDk2ZcY6biWqeBnQR8gzUN4="
            + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
private PrivateKey privateKey = null;

try {
    String privKey = testPrivateKeyPEM.replaceAll("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
    .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "").replaceAll("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKey));
PrivateKey privKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
System.err.println(privKey2.getAlgorithm()); //returns RSA
System.err.println(privKey2.getFormat());
this.privateKey = privKey2;
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//
//Once I read the private key, I create a cipher:
Cipher cipher =  null;
try
  {
//   cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
//   cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
   cipher = Cipher.getInstance(privateKey.getAlgorithm());
  }
  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        if (cipher == null)
         return;
try
 {
   cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
  }
  catch (InvalidKeyException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
String myString = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrSecond.getBytes()));
```

Comment: RSA is limited to encrypting very small messages. It's often used for key transport rather than data encryption. That is, you generate a random symmetric key and encrypt your plaintext using that key using an algorithm like AES. Then you encrypt the symmetric key using RSA, and send the RSA-encrypted key to the recipient along with the ciphertext.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security

Comment: You need to read the SAML specification on how to decrypt, or use a SAML / XML-Enc library. That data is not **just** RSA encrypted, it is encrypted using an RSA based certificate according to XML-Enc. Please edit in the encrypted message(s) so we can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You linked to an online service for decryption and on that site you have options for the **key** encryption method and another option for the **data** encryption method.

As @dnault already mentioned there are two steps:

step 1: decrypt the encrypted AES-key with your private key

step 2: decrypt the data using the decrypted AES key (please use the correct mode for decryption).

The picture shows the option fields:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.I have used THIS site to decrypt the message, and this is why I know that my private key is working on the encrypted data.
HOW do I decrypt from Java code?

Comment: If I fill out the website, then it will decrypt. I need to do it from inside the application.
I don't know what to put in The screen above.
I have created an SP Metadata, passed over to my client and after logging in, I have received the encrypted code. I can use a website to test/verify decryption, but I have to build a Java code to read the content.
Still trying to figure out how can I post a screen capture here.

Comment: @Geza Szivos: search for 'hybrid encryption with rsa' and you will get a lot of examples. Thats the same as dnault wrote in his comment.

Comment: After searching for 'hybrid encryption with rsa' ; now ending up searching for 'Importing a GitHub project into Eclipse'. 
:=)
Thanks for the help!